# How to save a web page on archive.org that has a "Accepting cookies" question button?

Tags: archive.org

The following web page is an example of a web page that cannot be easily saved on archive.org because it has  "Accepting cookies" question button, which missing on the captured page.

- https://www.golem.de/news/kuenstliche-intelligenz-so-funktioniert-chatgpt-2302-171644.html

Archive.org seems to save the capture page in this case, but may not save the page behind the capture, or at least not let you get to it easily. See follow one, with missing "Yes I accept cookies" button, left beside the existing green button.

- https://web.archive.org/web/20230208142622/https://www.golem.de/sonstiges/zustimmung/auswahl.html?from=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.golem.de%2Fnews%2Fkuenstliche-intelligenz-so-funktioniert-chatgpt-2302-171644.html

How can I save this web page to archive.org anyway ?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please read [SAVE PAGES IN THE WAYBACK MACHINE](https://help.archive.org/help/save-pages-in-the-wayback-machine/). If you need further help `tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!` (taken from [ask])

Answer (score 4):

It's not quite the same, but if you save the files on your computer, you may be able to [upload them to Archive.org](https://archive.org/create/) (if "you have the right to share"). The [largest image uploader](https://archive.org/details/pastpages) on the site is an account that exclusively uploads older "news homepage screenshots", in fact.

Alternatively, whenever Archive.org fails me, I go to a different archive site. In this case, Archive.today was able to save the page, which can be seen at [archive.is/T8Ams](https://archive.is/T8Ams).

For whatever reason, the original website changed to annoying pagination, but Archive.today is also able to work with those URLs.

It's not clear to me how or why it's able to save the page. When I use cURL, for example, the page gives a 30X response, and it always sends me to the cookie page without giving any of the original article.

Answer (score 0):

It looks that the page that you want to archive using the Wayback Machine is amnong the cases that can't be saved by this tool because the URL redirects to

`https://www.golem.de/sonstiges/zustimmung/auswahl.html?from=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.golem.de%2Fnews%2Fkuenstliche-intelligenz-so-funktioniert-chatgpt-2302-171644.html`

a page, as you mentioned, ask the user to take certain action, in this case accept cookies, which could not be done by the **Save page now**, and the Wayback Machine browser extensions.

The other options given by archive.org regarding Wayback Machine are to join the Archive Team or to susbribe to Archive-IT.

The source and details of the above are in [SAVE PAGES IN THE WAYBACK MACHINE](https://help.archive.org/help/save-pages-in-the-wayback-machine/)

On Software Recommendations there is a post that asked for alternatives to the Wayback Machine -> [Alternatives to archive.org](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/45379/14228) .